# Unterminated JSX content

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <h2>hello</h2>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
} 

export default App;
```

ERROR in [eslint]
src\App.jsx
Line 11:7:  Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents. (11:7)

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 920 ms

Why seeing this "Unterminated JSX contents" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML tags do not open and close properly. Your code

```
<>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <h2>hello</h2>
  <BrowserRouter/>
</>
```

Basically contains two opening `BrowserRouter` elements, where the second one is a self-closing one (containing `/` at the end of the tag).
You probably want to have a closing tag, so moving `/` to the start of the tag should be enough in order to close it again.

Therefore you should use:

```
<>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <h2>hello</h2>
  </BrowserRouter>
</>
```